# Calculate a pandas dataframe column with text and another field

Tags: python, pandas

I want to populate a column with another field and text.
You can calculate a column with another column like this:

```
DF["column_name1"] = DF["column_name2"]
```

And you can calculate it with text like this

```
DF["column_name1"] = "TEXT"
```

How do I combine the two? For example I want to get:

```
column_name1
| column_name1 | column_name2 |
| ------------ | ------------ |
| 1            | MN-1         |
| 2            | MN-2         |
| 3            | MN-3         |
```

How do I get every column to start with "MN" and then the number from column_name1?
I could create a new column, populate it with "MN" and then delete it later but
that seems like extra steps.

Thanks for your help.

Thanks for your help! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way you do with calculating other columns, just make sure to convert the other column's value to a string first:

```py
# Create simple dataframe
DF = pd.DataFrame([{"column_name1":1}, {"column_name1":2}, {"column_name1":3}])

# Calculate string column
DF["column_name2"] = "MN-" + DF["column_name1"].astype(str)

print(DF)
```

This yields:

```
   column_name1 column_name2
0             1         MN-1
1             2         MN-2
2             3         MN-3
```